# A new component.ts file appeared out of nowhere

Tags: angular

I renamed on of my component files yesterday, and everything was going ok, the project was compiling without errors. However this morning, I get the following error when compiling:
ERROR in src/app/ressources/new-name/new-name.component-DESKTOP-NAME-OF-MY-DESKTOP.ts(214,5): error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Ressource[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

This referred to an error that had happened yesterday but had been solved. And the file new-name.component-DESKTOP-NAME-OF-MY-DESKTO.ts had poped up alongside the regular new-name.component-.ts. Does anyone know what this is and why it appeared?

PS: I'm using Angular 8

Comment: are you seriously using dropbox or sth like this as version control?

Comment: No, I'm using git. What could have triggered this to appear?

Comment: At first check whether every open file is saved. Then try to clear angular cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the server repository. If the file is there, that's your problem and a pull request need to be made to fix it.

Otherwise, your local repo is out of sync. I've found that trying to troubleshoot that isn't worth the effort when it's easier to just fix it.

From the command line, navigate to any directory within your repository, then try `git status`

The response should tell you what branch you're in and what file changes aren't committed yet. If you're in the right branch *and you don't mind losing all changes not already pushed to the server repository*, you can clear up any discrepancies between what you have and what *should* be there with the following commands...

1. `git reset -hard HEAD` to lose all local changes to the branch.
2. `git pull -f` to refresh your local repository from the server,
   overriding any local conflicts you might have.
3. `git clean -fxd` to
   delete every file in your local repo that isn't tracked as part of the repo, including the NODE_MODULES folder.
4. `npm install` to reinstall the npm packages (because `git clean -fxd` deleted everything in NODE_MODULES)

This takes a while, and it's definitely overkill almost every time I've needed it, but as long as you are sure your local repo doesn't have unpushed commits or other changes you and to keep, it solves the problem!